# implementar template html en proyecto laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, bootstrap

He creado un proyecto php con laravel 5.4, he configurado todo correctamente y funciona todo a la perfección, he comprado un template ya completo para implementarlo a mi proyecto, realizado en bootstrap, y se que se puede usar con laravel, mi problema es el siguiente, el template por defecto trae todos los ficheros en html, pero claro laravel trabaja con ".blade.php" y he conseguido transformar todos los ficheros a .blade.php, pero ya que es una plantilla profesional, en los distintos html hay referencias a los otros htmls, y entonces al estar en .blade.php no detecta esos ficheros html, mi pregunta seria, si con laravel hay alguna posibilidad de incluir dicha plantilla en html, o bien en blade pero cambiando las referencias a los otros ficheros? que no sea ir uno por uno. 
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Para incluir archivos `.blade.php` en blade:

```
@include('directorio.archivo')
```

Esto si se quiere incluir el archivo: `resources/views/directorio/archivo.blade.php`

En los href tienes que poner las rutas a las que direccionan.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero con las vistas .blade.php puedo trabajar sin ningun problema, tengo algun lio con las rutas a veces que me fallan, pero el problema es que el template que compre estan los htmls interelacionados y al conversionarlos a .blade.php, los href="index.html" que hacen referencia a los htmls no se cambian y tengo que ir uno por uno. Entonces simplemente quiero saber si, puedo usar html con laravel, si hay alguna manera para implementar el proyecto a la plantilla, no la plantilla al proyecto En esta otra pregunta de otro usuario nombran un poco lo que pretendo yo:

Comment: Entonces lo que tienes que hacer es cambiar los href por las rutas correspondientes

Comment: Muchas gracias! aunque para ser laravel me parece poco automatizado para tal y como funcionan las cosas. y aun son bastantes rutas..

Comment: estas seguro que ese "template" que has comprado es valido para laravel?  Yo todas las plantillas que he encontrado para comprar solo son html+css+js, no vienen preparadas para twig (yo uso symfony)... siempre me ha tocado adaptar dichas plantillas al formato correspondiente.